# How to print PDF document from Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have windows service that must periodically print PDF document from server. My function is

```
private void PrintFormPdfData(byte[] formPdfData)
{
    string tempFile;

    tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(formPdfData, 0, formPdfData.Length);
        fs.Flush();
    }

    string pdfArguments = string.Format("/p /h\"{0}\"", tempFile);

    string pdfPrinterLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";


    ProcessStartInfo newProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(pdfPrinterLocation, pdfArguments);
    newProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;
    newProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    newProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
    newProcess.RedirectStandardError = true;

    Process pdfProcess = new Process();
    pdfProcess.StartInfo = newProcess;
    pdfProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    pdfProcess.Start();
    pdfProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

When I implement this in Windows Application it works, but when I implement in Windows service it does not work.

Can you help me?

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved problem with Session 0. I use this class:

```
public class ProcessStarter : IDisposable
{
    #region Import Section

    private static uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
    private static uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000;
    private static uint TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    private static uint TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    private static uint TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
    private static uint TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    private static uint TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
    private static uint TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
    private static uint TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY);
    private static uint TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID);

    private const uint NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x0020;

    private const uint CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;


    private const uint MAX_PATH = 260;

    private const uint CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;

    private const uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }

    public enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
    {
        SecurityAnonymous,
        SecurityIdentification,
        SecurityImpersonation,
        SecurityDelegation
    }

    public enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
        TokenPrimary = 1,
        TokenImpersonation
    }

    public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
        public Int32 SessionID;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public String pWinStationName;

        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(int sessionId, out IntPtr tokenHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr existingToken, uint desiredAccess, IntPtr tokenAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL impersonationLevel, TOKEN_TYPE tokenType, out IntPtr newToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr token, string applicationName, string commandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes, bool inheritHandles, uint creationFlags, IntPtr environment, string currentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO startupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetLastError();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr token, uint timeInterval);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int WTSEnumerateSessions(System.IntPtr hServer, int Reserved, int Version, ref System.IntPtr ppSessionInfo, ref int pCount);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(out IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr memory);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr lpEnvironment);

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ProcessStarter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ProcessStarter()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ProcessStarter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processName">Name of the process.</param>
    /// <param name="fullExeName">Full name of the exe.</param>
    public ProcessStarter(string processName, string fullExeName)
    {
        processName_ = processName;
        processPath_ = fullExeName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ProcessStarter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processName">Name of the process.</param>
    /// <param name="fullExeName">Full name of the exe.</param>
    /// <param name="arguments">The arguments.</param>
    public ProcessStarter(string processName, string fullExeName, string arguments)
    {
        processName_ = processName;
        processPath_ = fullExeName;
        arguments_ = arguments;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current user token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IntPtr GetCurrentUserToken()
    {
        IntPtr currentToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

        int dwSessionId = 0;
        IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero;

        IntPtr pSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        int dwCount = 0;

        WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, ref pSessionInfo, ref dwCount);

        Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

        Int32 current = (int)pSessionInfo;
        for (int i = 0; i < dwCount; i++)
        {
            WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            if (WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive == si.State)
            {
                dwSessionId = si.SessionID;
                break;
            }

            current += dataSize;
        }

        WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

        bool bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, out currentToken);
        if (bRet == false)
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        bRet = DuplicateTokenEx(currentToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out primaryToken);
        if (bRet == false)
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        return primaryToken;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {

        IntPtr primaryToken = GetCurrentUserToken();
        if (primaryToken == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return;
        }
        STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        processInfo_ = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        StartupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(StartupInfo);

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security1 = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security2 = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();

        string command = "\"" + processPath_ + "\"";
        if ((arguments_ != null) && (arguments_.Length != 0))
        {
            command += " " + arguments_;
        }

        IntPtr lpEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool resultEnv = CreateEnvironmentBlock(out lpEnvironment, primaryToken, false);
        if (resultEnv != true)
        {
            int nError = GetLastError();
        }

        CreateProcessAsUser(primaryToken, null, command, ref Security1, ref Security2, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpEnvironment, null, ref StartupInfo, out processInfo_);

        DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
        CloseHandle(primaryToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process current in processes)
        {
            if (current.ProcessName == processName_)
            {
                current.Kill();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for exit.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int WaitForExit()
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo_.hProcess, INFINITE);
        int errorcode = GetLastError();
        return errorcode;
    }



    #region IDisposable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    private string processPath_ = string.Empty;
    private string processName_ = string.Empty;
    private string arguments_ = string.Empty;
    private PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo_;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the process path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The process path.</value>
    public string ProcessPath
    {
        get
        {
            return processPath_;
        }
        set
        {
            processPath_ = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the process.</value>
    public string ProcessName
    {
        get
        {
            return processName_;
        }
        set
        {
            processName_ = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the arguments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The arguments.</value>
    public string Arguments
    {
        get
        {
            return arguments_;
        }
        set
        {
            arguments_ = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my function look like:

```
private void PrintFormPdfData(byte[] formPdfData)
{
    string tempFile;

    tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(formPdfData, 0, formPdfData.Length);
        fs.Flush();
    }
    string pdfArguments =string.Format("/t /o {0} \"Printer name\"", tempFile);

    string pdfPrinterLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";

    try
    {
        ProcessStarter processStarter = new ProcessStarter("AcroRd32", pdfPrinterLocation, pdfArguments);
        processStarter.Run();
        processStarter.WaitForExit();
        processStarter.Stop();
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(tempFile);
    }
}
```

Also, `ServiceProcessInstaller` must have `Account set to "LocalSystem". When I created service I set to "Local service" with this user it does not work. I did not try with "Network service" or "User".

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with the registry edits found in this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184291.

Printing from Windows services (and also IIS) uses the SYSTEM account as I understand it.  This account does not have access to the printer but these registry edits gives that SYSTEM account printing privileges.

Here is a summary:

1. export 3 keys ("folders within regedit.exe") to .reg files:

   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Devices
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\PrinterPorts
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Windows
2. edit your 3 newly created reg files and change "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" to "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT"
3. run your 3 reg files by double clicking them in explorer (this adds them to the registry)

That's all it takes.  This helped me to print pdf files to a printer from PHP in IIS 7.  My php script would work just fine so long as the server happened to have the Administrator logged in when the script was run.  Now no one needs to be logged in and the script still works :)

I hope this saves someone as much searching and tinkering as I put in to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the OS, but I suspect you are running into the [Session 0 isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx) feature that was added in Windows Vista, Server 2008 and subsequent OS releases

Application classes affected by this feature include:

Services that create UI.

A service that tries to use window-message functions such as SendMessage and PostMessage to communicate with an application.

Applications creating globally named objects.

Comment: I am currently running on windows 7. But later I will need to run on XP nad Windows 7 or vista. I do not have any errors when I run or debug this function.

Comment: Yeah , it won't throw and error but you won't see the expected results at runtime. However, have you tried on a Windows XP machine to see if the print actually works, that will confirm if this is a session 0 thing, because Windows XP doesn't have S0 isolation