# Printing excel,Pdf document using windows service

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, ms-word

I want to print pdf,excel,word documents using windows service in c#. Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You question quite complicate and not clearly. However, I try to give you some of links to help you. You can reference links below:

[How to print PDF document from Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596394/how-to-print-pdf-document-from-windows-service)

or

[Printing from a .NET Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990/printing-from-a-net-service)